# Select multiple elements from same column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to return something from my db and I don't get what I want.
I have a query that returns me this :

```
[{username: 'tupac',
age: 20,
popularity: 35,
city: 'Paris',
country: 'France',
latitude: 48.8534,
longitude: 2.3488,
tag_id: 172 }]
```

But what if there are multiples entries in the tag_id column ?
 Can I return this ? They way I have it today returns me 3 objects if there are 3 tag_id.
So if tupac has 3 or 4 tag_id linked to him can I have something like this ?

```
[{username: 'tupac',
age: 20,
popularity: 35,
city: 'Paris',
country: 'France',
latitude: 48.8534,
longitude: 2.3488,
tag_id: 172 
tag_id: 173
tag_id: 175} ]
```

This is my actual query :

```
SELECT usersinfo.username, usersinfo.age, 
usersinfo.popularity, userlocation.city, userlocation.country, 
userlocation.latitude, userlocation.longitude , user_tags.tag_id

FROM usersinfo, userlocation, user_tags
WHERE usersinfo.sex = "f" 
AND usersinfo.orientation = "s" 
AND usersinfo.username = userlocation.username 
AND usersinfo.username = user_tags.username
AND usersinfo.username != 'natedogg'
```

I've been reading some stuff and neither the operator 'IN' or 'GROUP_CONTACT' Can help me. Maybe I'm doing this wrong ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you have a delimiter of a sort in the TagID column, like a comma or semi-colon between the values?

Comment: Could you post your data schema? Is there a related field between user_tags table and userinfo?

Comment: what is user_tags refering to? are those tags saved in a separate table?

Comment: @Sepultura Yes, basically I've created one table where I save the tags as a 'string' and giving them an id and another one where I can refer to it by the tag_id.

Comment: @DanielG no I don't have anything.

Comment: @McNets Yes, the username is the related field, I based my database on usernames. So someone in usersinfo will have his username in every other tables

Comment: Then there are really three tags for this user, is it?

Comment: @McNets Yes this user has 3 tags, but i will return me 3 object (the same with a different tag id every time)

Comment: apparently I can't, I've just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996135/returning-a-two-dimensional-array-from-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    usersinfo.username, 
    usersinfo.age, 
    usersinfo.popularity, 
    userlocation.city, 
    userlocation.country, 
    userlocation.latitude, 
    userlocation.longitude , 
    (select group_concat(user_tags.tag_id)
     from user_tags
     where user_tags.username = usersinfo.username
     group by username) as tag_id
FROM usersinfo
    inner join userlocation on usersinfo.username = userlocation.username 
WHERE usersinfo.sex = "f" 
AND usersinfo.orientation = "s" 
AND usersinfo.username = user_tags.username
AND usersinfo.username != 'natedogg';
```

Notice I've change your where clause and I've added a join.

Comment: I've tried it, it returns me `Unknown column 'user_tags.username' in 'where clause'`

Comment: does this column exists?

Comment: Of course. my table user_tags has : id, tag_id and username